# Create mirror function using pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to implement pattern matching for a few simple types. In particular, I want to define a function `mirror` that mirrors circles and rectangles.

That is,

```
mirror[Circle[{1,2},3]] == Circle[{1,-2},3]
mirror[Rectangle[{4,5},{6,7}]] == Rectangle[{4,-5},{6,-7}]
```

In languages such as Haskell, this is done via pattern matching:

```
mirror (Circle x y) = Circle x (-y)
```

etc. but when I tried to do the same in Mathematica, the expression did not evaluate:

```
mirror[obj_] := Switch[obj,
    Circle[{x, y}, r], Circle[{x,-y},r]
];
```

Is there a way to achieve this functionality in Mathematica?

Comment: `mirror[ Circle[{x_, y_}, r_] ] := Circle[{x,-y},r]` please read everything related to [**tutorial/Introduction-Patterns**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html).

Comment: funny that you mention Haskell; you'll notice from Kuba's example that something completely analogous (that is, *destructuring*) is being used in *Mathematica* as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pattern matching, you might want to consider using [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion):

```
TransformedRegion[Circle[{1, 2}, 3], ReflectionTransform[{0,1}]]
```

> Circle[{1, -2}, 3]

Making a function to do this:

```
reflect[primitive_] := TransformedRegion[primitive, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]]
```

Then:

```
reflect[Circle[{1, 2}, 3]]
reflect[Rectangle[{4, 5}, {6, 7}]]
```

> Circle[{1, -2}, 3]
>
> Rectangle[{4, -7}, {6, -5}]